# Is the sentence ok with two verbs?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

> *The things you want to create is can only be complete when pigs fly.*

I just read the above sentence on the internet, which is to demonstrate how to use the idiom when pigs fly. I don't think it is correct, because there are two verbs in the main clause, is and be. But when I check it in Grammarly.com, it turns out that the sentence is ok. So I need your help.

Comment: Ignore Grammarly.  It’s not capable of evaluating English sentences properly.

Answer (score 0):

No, this sentence is not OK as it is.

> The things you want to create **can** only be complete[d] when pigs fly

or

> The things you want to create **will** only be complete when pigs fly

Are both grammaticaly correct, but not idiomatic. Also, they have slightly different meanings.

Neither option conveys the meaning of *incredulity* that you likely wish to evoke.

---

An idiomatic equivalent could be

> The things you want to create will only be [possible] when pigs fly

or, possibly in a conversation, as "when pigs fly" is a rather colloquial phrase

> That will only happen when pigs fly

as a response to them describing what they wish to create.